# Compiling Java hardware API to run in Android.

Tags: java, android, compiler-construction, compilation

I am a bit of a noob to Android.

I have a project that utilizes a sensor glove to input data in the from of sensor values to a device. The objective of my project is to interface this sensor glove with an Android device so that the information from the glove is sent wireleslly to the Android device where my application would do the necessary processing.

The glove came with a set of tools and APIs to program in Java with. My question is basically, can i compile my code written in java to work on the Android platform? I reference a set of Jar files in my original code. Will i be able to utilize the same Jar files when running my code in Android, or would i be able to compile the same java code to run in Android.

really appreciate the help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the jar contains compiled class files, it won't work.  Your source code has to be compiled to work with the dalvik virtual machine, not java.

However, if you have the uncompiled class files, it will (likely) work with Android.  Most standard Java libraries are also available on Android.

Comment: This^  Also, any native code (if any) that is included with the library will have to be written compatable with the device (or ported to pure java)

Comment: Right, so you may have to rewrite your native code or alter it to work with the Android NDK.

Comment: Unfortuanalty i don't have access to the class files. The company that owns the glove has only provided JARs. Is there a way around working with an API like the one i'm dealing with. 

Maybe say use the Android bluetooth api to bring in the data and then filter the information out to what i need. How hard do you think that would be?